# Spring - stop bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, postconstruct

My bean implements InitializingBean and in the afterPropertiesSet method I want to perform validation.

The thing is that my validation uses some other bean which are not totaly finished loaded at this point, beans like JPA beans..

I used also `@PostConstruct` annotation - this is even worse since this method invoke before the `afterPropertiesSet` method.. Any suggestion how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried with the "depends-on" setting in the Spring definition?

Comment: Yes I did try it, didn't help... also tried lazy-init didn't worked either

Comment: btw , the bean which I'm using for the validation is Autowired in 

my bean (the one that implements InitializingBean)

Comment: Can you provide more information in your question? You have a bean that implements InitializingBean, which depends on a validator, which depends on the entitymanagerfactorybean? Or does it have an EntityManager field (with PersistenceContext annotation) What is it that has not been initialized at this point? Etc..

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.
My bean implements IntializingBean, 
in the afterPropertiesSet I'm running my validator which depends on EntityManagerBean , which is not initialized.
hope that this is more clear. thanks!

Comment: Do you have more than one application context? Like, if you are developing a web application using Spring MVC, you have the parent application context and the servlet application context. The first one loaded by ContextLoaderListener, the latter loaded by DispatcherServlet. If you do, you can try loading the entitymanagerfactory in the parent context and your bean in the child context.

Comment: Show us the code of your `afterPropertiesSet`, especially how you access `EntityManager` and how are you obtaining it?

Comment: What is ominous here is the phrase 'perform validation'. What kind of validation are we talking about? I suspect you might have to approach this problem a bit differently....

Comment: Luciani,
you were right , I do have more than one application context.
entityManagerFactory is in the parent context and my bean is in the child context. the thing is that I have multithreaded processes for loading components (which not depends on any other component) within separate thread and workaround entitymanager is too heavy that is why isn't not fully initialized in the afterPropertiesSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by implementing PostInit annotation

the annotation insure that the method that using this annotation will be invoke only after all beans

within the application have been deployed.

good reference:
http://reteptools.kenai.com/api/retepMicroKernel/snapshot/uk/org/retep/kernel/annotations/PostInit.html